# Notification for a chat widget

Tags: javascript, widget, internet-explorer-9

I have developed a javascript based widget application having IM features, use case of this widget will be to embed it on any web page.

we have embedded this widget app to our organizational portal, and IM is working fine. Now the management wants if we can have notification for any incoming IM, if the browser is minimized or is in the background. Notification on task bar as gtalk was providing on windows XP.

But now a days, these notifications are not available on windows 7, even facebook has an messenger embedded with their FB page and even no notification is there.

I searched internet for solution but as of now found nothing. It seems for desktop application it can be done for widget kind of application is it feasible??

Please help..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the window title to the notification. This is similar to what Facebook does.

http://heyman.info/2010/sep/30/jquery-title-alert/

This should help you out.